# How can I redirect another view page in the list in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, http-redirect

How can I redirect to another view page when the 'overtimerequest' tab is clicked?

```
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="getAllOvertimeList()" href="#home">All</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href=  >OverTimeRequest</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="getAllOvertimeListFilter(durum='Beklemede')" href="#menu1">Acceptable</a></li>
```

Comment: I tried 
asp-controller="FazlaMesai" asp-action="OverTimeRequest" 
 and 
href="@Url.Action("OverTimeRequest", "FazlaMesai") but neither did.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: super random but getAllOvertimeListFilter method can call javascript and In javascript, you can call a controller method and inside the controller, you can use the routing extension method like RedirectToAction and in that action, you can return a different view of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `data-toggle="tab"` attribute, Bootstrap expects that you are using a reference to a section inside the same html.

You can see the generate html node, the href is auto setted as `href="#tab"`, so the tag helper or override the href has no affects.

I think if you want to redirect to another view, there is no need to use the tab, just remove `data-toggle="tab"`.

Comment: yes, I tried that and it happened. thank you!